# How to read DropDownList value with HTML Helper when using @Html.PagedListPager MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, pagedlist

I have the following code in my view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Number of Records to Show:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.NumRecsToShow, Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(i => new SelectListItem {Text = i.ToString(), Value = i.ToString()}))
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList) Model.lp, page => Url.Action("List", new RouteValueDictionary()
        {
            {"Page",page},
            {"Recs",?????}
        }))
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do is read the new selected value and pass it back as a "Recs" parameter, so I can return the right number of Records.  But I dont know how to read the selected value when the PagedListPager number is clicked on in the table.  I would love to know of some @Html helper (Where the ???? is in the code above.) that can read the value when I need it, but I am starting to think that I might need to use JQuery.  Of course the other route would be if I can use the DropdownList to change the model data then I can just pass back the model to the controller, but the dropdownlist doesnt seem to get read unless I do a form submit.
Any pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: `@Html.PagedListPager()` is razor code - its parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Anything you put in `{"Recs",?????}` is the original value, not a value that is edited in the view. You need javascript if you wat to update the value of the url generated by `Url.Action()`. But the typical way of handling this is to have the dropdownlist in a form (with `FormMethod.Get`) and post the value back to your method.